# How do I add site meta in orchard cms

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I am trying to add og meta tags to my site for the facebook like button. How can I add that to the site's `<head>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple methods:

1. There is no _Layout.cshtml in Orchard. The equivalent would be Document.cshtml in your Theme. You can do what Freeman suggested, but in Document.cshtml
2. You can use one of the existing Facebook modules on the Orchard gallery. There is at least one module there that implements the Like button, so you can attach the "like" buttons to your parts and the module will take care of the `<head>` tags for you.

Comment: I went with option 1. I didn't know about making an alternate for Document.cshtml in the theme, thanks for the help :)